# Admob Native Ad blocking UI thread

Tags: android, admob, adsense, native-ads

I have tried to implement Admob Native Ads into my Android App. But I have problem with this. My app has been blocking UI Thread when the ad is being loaded.
I have used Native Ads for recyclerview. This is example for that which I have forked from google example repository and modify for the same with my implementation.

https://github.com/sinhpn92/admob-native-ad-example

I have tried to put the load ads inside asynctask or kotlin coroutines thread but It's still have this problem. I did upgrade to latest version.

I have some question:

- Have anyone has facing this issue?.
- Is that problem of admob sdk?.
- Have any suggest to solve this issue?.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya. No I didn't. I just to use delay 3 seconds to load ads :((. 
I did create the issue to question in the github but do not have any solution to solve :((
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/211#issuecomment-591225565

Comment: Yup same issue I am facing as well